# C# - Servicestack MongoDB JSON Objects Unescape

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I have got two problems.

I have a local MongoDB with several collections.

A DataBase Object looks like this:

[image: Database]

My Configuration looks like this:

```
​using Funq;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;
namespace protocol.server.API
{
    public class ApiHost : AppSelfHostBase
    {
        public ApiHost() : base("Api REST Service", typeof(ApiHost).Assembly)
        {
        }
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {
                DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
                    EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Html)
            });
            JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;

        }
    }
}
```

My GET Request definition is this:
            public async Task Get(GetObjects request)
            {
                var collection = Connect.*database.GetCollection("Cylinders");
                var aggregate = collection.Find(* => true);
                var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
                return results;
            }

```
using ServiceStack;
namespace protocol.server.API.Clients
{
    [Route("/objects")]
    public class GetObjects : IReturn<string>
    {
    }
}

using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDBTest;
using ServiceStack;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace protocol.server.API.Clients
{
    public class ClientService : ServiceStack.Service
    {
        public async Task<object> Get(GetObjects request)
        {
            var collection = Connect._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Cylinders");
            var aggregate = collection.Find(_ => true);
            var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();

            return results;
        }

    }
}
```

Problem 1: My JSON Objects are not escaped and they look quite strange (backslahes and so on).

Problem 2 (Aggregation): I want to aggregate all Objects in specific format.

I wrote this:

```
var collection = Connect._database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Cylinders");
           var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Group(new BsonDocument {
               { "_id", "$_id" },
           });
          var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
```

this works perfectly, but if I want to aggregate more fields, it does not work:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate().Group(new BsonDocument {
               { "_id", "$_id" },
               { "AvailableAt", "$description.availableat" }
           });​
```

How to solve the problems?

Comment: Using `UseBclJsonSerializers = true` says to use .NET's built-in JSON Serializer which negates any `JsConfig.*` option which only apply to ServiceStack's Text serializers.

Comment: It's not clear what your `GetObjects` Service has to do with Mongo since it seems unrelated (if it is ask 2 separate questions with clear explanation of what the issue is on each + enough context + code to be able to repro the issue). For the ServiceStack Service it's unusual to return a JSON string in a ServiceStack Service. Just return the `results` object without the `[AddHeader]` attribute and let ServiceStack automatically naturally serialize the response to JSON for clients who Request a JSON Response.

Comment: Hey and thanks. I removed the UseBclJsonSerialisers = true and the AddHeader attribute as well.

I added the GetObjects Method as well, see my Code above.

Comment: Please read my Answer, you should be returning a clean `Cyclinder` POCO, not a `BsonDocument`.

Comment: @mythz I'm sorry, I was editing and you were so fast, that you wrote the comment before I edited it. I wrote my comment before I edited it.

Is it right that way ? Please see GetObjects as well.

I cannot specify the Task Return of GetObjects, because there are not only Cylinders in the Database.

Comment: Nothing in your updated question suggests you've actually read my answer. Your service should return **clean POCOs** NOT a serialized JSON string or a `BsonDocument`. e.g. you should be using `IReturn<List<Cylinder>>` and your Service returning something like `Task<List<Cylinder>>`.

Comment: @mythz I don't have a class named "Cylinder" at all. What should it contain and look like?

Comment: Look at [MongoDB's support for POCOs](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+mongodb+poco) here's a [couple](https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/08/04/mongodb-in-net-part-3-starting-with-poco-documents/) of [examples](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/mongodb-with-c-deep-dive/240152181). If you don't want to use Mongo DB's built-in support for POCOs you can **manually copy** data from a `BsonDocument` into a plain C# `Cylinder` class (i.e. POCO).

Comment: Hey @mythz I took a look at your tutorial and it is quite easy to understand.
But I've got one question.

I want to use the standard serialization but have an array in my MongoDB, which causes some problems.

In C# I have written this:

 public Object[] media; 

and the error is:

Expected a nested document representing the serialized form of a protocol.server.API.Clients.Cylinder+des value, but found a value of type Array instead

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to return a JSON string in a ServiceStack Service as it prohibits being able to access the Response in any other format and prevents many other of ServiceStack's surrounding metadata features around your Services.

Your Services should be returning clean POCO's which can then be serialized in any registered format, returning a `BsonDocument` is a poor response to serialize and explains why you're getting escaped JSON as you're serializing an object that contains JSON in a string instead of a clean DTO.

So you should change your Services to return clean POCO's with something like:

```
public async Task<List<Cylinder>> Get(GetObjects request)
{
    var collection = Connect._database.GetCollection<Cylinder>();
    var aggregate = collection.Find(_ => true);
    var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
    return results;
}
```